# How to set three buttons horizontally without gap using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, xcode6, autolayout

I have a requirement where , i try to set 3 buttons at the bottom of the view horizontally placed without any gap . I have attached a screen shot of how i need to show and another showing how it displays currently.

i am using the following constraint programatically to set this

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(btnCreateAccount,btnForgotuserid,btnForgotPassword);

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btnCreateAccount attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[btnCreateAccount][btnForgotuserid(==btnCreateAccount)][btnForgotPassword(==btnCreateAccount)]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:views]];
```

[image: required]
[image: Actual]

Please help me in solving this issue

EDIT : In iOS 7 , see the screen shot

[image]

Thanks,
Vinod.

Comment: Is doing this in interface builder an option? I know how to do it there...

Comment: Otherwise, I would set each button's width to be  W where W is a metric-- 1/3 the width of the view containing the buttons. metrics:@{@"W":1.0/3.0*buttonsSuperView.width}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and the constraints seem to work fine. The problem might be somewhere else.

This is the code I have tried, created all buttons programmatically:

```
UIButton *b1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIButton *b2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIButton *b3 = [[UIButton alloc] init];

for (UIButton *b in @[b1, b2, b3]) {
    [b setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
    [b.layer setBorderWidth:1];
}
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:b1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[b1]-0-[b2(==b1)]-0-[b3(==b1)]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom metrics:nil views:@{ @"b1":b1, @"b2":b2, @"b3":b3 }]];
```

Make sure you are calling `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` on your buttons. If you create them in the storyboard, you need to remove the implicit constraints that are added there.

Let me know how this goes and if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Catalina Thanks for the help . It works in iOS 8 across various screens sizes but not in iOS 7 . Am i missing something here

Comment: Take a look at my horizontal constraints, the space is explicitly set to 0 between the buttons. Did you make that change to your code? That makes it work for me also on iOS7, I just tried it

Comment: i used your code and ran in ios 7 simulator but still i get that screen which i attached

Comment: Thanks this is working fine :) i removed the buttons from story board and created programatically and its working fine in iOS 7.0

Comment: That's awesome! You're welcome :) Good luck with your project